# How do we access the value of dcc.store in plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am using dash by plotly to create a dashboard. I want to save a variable from one page so I can use it in another page. I am trying to use dcc.store for the same. But while trying to access it, I am getting the following error: Property "value" was used with component ID: "getComm" in one of the Input items of a callback. This ID is assigned to a dash_core_components. Store component in the layout, which does not support this property.

This is the code in my index file:

```
dcc.Store(id='getComm')
```

It's value is being written in page1.py
And I am trying to access it in the callback in page2.py:

```
@callback(
    ...
    Input('getComm', 'value')
)
```

How do we access the value in another page?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `data` instead of `value` (see [Store Properties](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store#store-properties)) :

```py
@callback(
    ...
    Input('getComm', 'data')
)
```

Also you might want to be specific about the `storage_type` (defaults to `'memory'`), eg.

```py
dcc.Store(id='getComm', storage_type='local')
```

Nb. You need to declare the `dcc.Store` in the main app file (eg. app.py) so that you can refer to it as a callback Input/Output/State in any of the pages within the app. See for example this [demo](https://github.com/AnnMarieW/dash-multi-page-app-demos/tree/main/multi_page_store).

Comment: I am getting an error of using a non-existent object in the callback. How should I declare it to be able to access it in another file?

Comment: You need to declare the dcc.Store in your main app file. See my edit above.